# CHECK (table1.integer >= table2.integer)

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

I need to create a CHECK constraint to verify that the entered integer in a column is greater than or equal to the integer in another column in a different table.

For example, the following tables would be valid:

```
=# SELECT * FROM table1;
 current_project_number
------------------------
                     12

=# SELECT * FROM table2;
 project_name | project_number
--------------+----------------
 Schaf        |              1
 Hase         |              8
 Hai          |             12
```

And the following tables would NOT be valid:

```
=# SELECT * FROM table1;
 current_project_number
------------------------
                     12

=# SELECT * FROM table2;
 project_name | project_number
--------------+----------------
 Schaf        |              1
 Hase         |              8
 Hai          |             12
 Erdmännchen  |             71    <-error:table1.current_project_number is NOT >= 71
```

Please note this CHECK constraint is designed to make sure info like above cannot be inserted. I'm not looking to SELECT values where current_project_number >= project_number, this is about INSERTing

What would I need in order for such a CHECK to work? Thanks

Comment: From where are you getting values for table2 to be inserted. Based on this i can answer query to have this check in this place

Comment: @sardar I am manually specifying the number myself. It is not sourced from any other tables

Comment: In that case always have <insert statement for table2> where project_number <=select max(current_project_number) from table1

Comment: @sardar I'm sorry I don't understand. Can you please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: You can use a `check` constraint, but you would need to write a user-defined function.  Alternatively, you can use a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, still new to SQL, could you please show me? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `CHECK` constraint that references another table is possible, but a seriously bad idea that will lead to problems in the future.

`CHECK` constraints are only validated when the table with the constraint on it is modified, *not* when the other table referenced in the constraint is modified. So it is possible to render the condition invalid with modifications on that second table.

In other words, PostgreSQL will not guarantee that the constraint is always valid. This can and will lead to unpleasant surprises, like a backup taken with `pg_dump` that can no longer be restored.

Don't go down that road.

If you need functionality like that, define a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `table1` that verifies the condition and throws an exception otherwise:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ins_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1
              WHERE NEW.project_number > current_project_number)
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'project number must be less than or equal to values in table1';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON table2
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_trig();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the opposite. I need to make sure that values in table2 ≤ the value in table1, aka 1<12, 8<12, 12=12, but 71≤12 error. I will be inserting info into table2, table1 will remain untouched

Comment: ^ I submitted an edit to your question to fulfill this

Comment: One other thing, how can I apply both the function and trigger to multiple tables? (e.g. make sure that table2 follows these rules, as well as table3 and table4). Almost like doing `CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON (table2, table3, table4)` but of course, not inserting data into all tables at once, only checking that if I insert data into table3 it will follow the same rules as if I were to insert data into table2 or table4. Hope this makes sense. Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Then you need a trigger on every table. Using dynamic SQL and [`TG_RELID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) you could use a single trigger function.